# disable plugin in specific dynamic buddypress pages

Tags: buddypress

I am using Buddypress and multiple plugins. I want to disable a specific plugin on a specific dynamic BP page.

How can I disable a plugin in a specific dynamic BP pages e.g. sitename.com/members/username/messages ?

Thanks

Comment: You could try this plugin. https://wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-organizer/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to solve this issue:

1) As mentioned above, Plugin Organizer is a popular plugin built to handle this sort of request.

2) Custom code, either in your theme or in the plugin itself. Knowing the inner workings of the plugin you are attempting to disable will be important if you decide to go the custom code route.

Previous answers to this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6774424/wordpress-disable-plugin-on-specific-pages-posts/